# Angular module is not available when reference in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have a basic Angular application that tries to add controllers and directives under a single module.  The module is declared in the top level javascript file called *app.js* and looks like the following:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("FooModule", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ]);

  // Code to setup config and routes here
})();
```

And in their own files, each controller or directive are created using code that looks like more or less like this ...

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('FooModule');

  app.controller('barCtlr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Controller Logic Here
  }]);
})();
```

When running, however, we are getting the error

```
Module 'FooModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it can't find the FooModule?

NOTE: When we create a module for each individual controller or directive it works fine.

*UPDATE*: So to make thing even more interesting is the fact that after getting the error, in the Javascript console, when I enter the following:

```
console.log(angular.module('FooModule'));
```

I don't get any errors and in fact do get a valid module object returned with all of the controllers and directives included.

Comment: you need to load those files in order

Comment: Yes, controller definition is loaded before app definition run.

Comment: @VuQuyet I've added the sequence in which the files are loaded above for further clarification.  Is that the incorrect order?

Comment: Yes, 'controller definition is loaded before app definition run' raised error, switch the order , add definition must be run at first (set), before any other ones can call to get it with: angular.module('FooModule')

Comment: @VuQuyet this is why I updated my example with the sequence that we load in.  As you can see, app.js is loaded before barCtlr.js so as far as I understand that is the correct order and the definition should already be set by the time we try to retrieve the module later on.  Is there something wrong with the load sequence in the example?

Comment: @raiglstorfer Is it full error description in console? Can you show full app.js file?

Comment: which version of angular is this? I have seen a few other questions that describe the same issue today, I'm curious if it has something to do with a specific angular release.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can not write it short with comments so I have an answer for this.

**One more things need to be in order**: Your app must be defined before bootstrap process happen. As [info from angular team here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap),

"Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'"

Mean that bootstrap will require your app definition already be there on time of bootstrap process happen.

So what you need to do is **move your app definition out of 'onready' event**.

Code in app.js should be:

```
var app = angular.module("FooModule", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

Without in (function(){})();

If you want to **control it manually** such as bootstrap process happen later by yourself, then you should **remove ng-app from your html** and bootstrap manually your app only when your app definition ready with:

```
// define your app first
angular.module('myApp', [])    

// then bootstrap it
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: If you don't use async script loading then DOMContentLoaded fired only when all scripts a loaded. With the right scripts order code abowe works correctly.

Comment: wrapping a function inside `(function(){})(); ` (IIFE) **does not** make this part of the jquery `onready` event.

Comment: @Claies: I'm wrong about (function(){})(); , not sure it run after bootstrap  but I met this error before and move out of (function(){})();; solve this problem. I still think error from 'app definition is not executed at the time bootstrap process'. Interesting.

Comment: @VuQuyet yep, for some reason that fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at your 'barCtlr.js'

The current code is:

```
app.controller('barCtlr'. ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

'barCtlr'. it should be a comma instead of a period like

```
app.controller('barCtlr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

Comment: Try to run code with period instead of a comma and you'll see another error message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but that was just a typo with StackOverflow.  The actual code had a comma, otherwise I wouldn't be getting the error listed.